# Eclipse Rich Client Platform, add Textbox or similar

Tags: java, eclipse, textbox, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I want to add something like a Textbox or a Texteditor to my project, I added Views and Commands and Toolbars etc., but cant seem to find what I am looking for, which is a Textfield or a editor which is placeable in that view or similar. Is there any way to do that? I am pretty new to RCP so, every little piece of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is much to vague. Add a text box where? Explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: That isn't much of an improvement. What do you mean by a 'Textfield placeable in a view'? If this is a view you are writing you use SWT controls to add whatever you like to the view.

Comment: Also is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP (using things the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point)?

Comment: ok, my situation: i have a RCP project (Plugin Developement project) and I do this just to get used to the Enviroment. I already added Views and Toolbar etc via Extension Points. So what I want to do: I want to add a Textfield/Texteditor o.s. into my already existing view. So, when I run the project I can type something into my GUI. I hope that explains it good. Thanks for your effort

Comment: So you add SWT controls to the view in the `createPartControl` method.

Comment: @greg-449 it seems to be a 3.x. compatibillity mode. Also my knowledge in that area is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Add *SWT* Controlls to the View-class into the `createPartControl` . Like : http://esus.com/creating-a-textarea/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [SWT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html). This has a nice introduction to SWT. There are a lot of informations about Layouting too, which would be the next issue you may encounter.